# alert only if i click the icon not the whole row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to get an alert when i click the icon not the whole row but for some reason I am getting it on the whole row. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="footer">
  <span id="scroll-top">
        <i class="fa fa-round fa-chevron-up"></i>
    </span>
</div>

.footer {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.footer .fa-round {
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  height: 34px;
  width: 34px;
}

.footer #scroll-top {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 99999999;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hgu02x0b/1/

Comment: Change `$("#scroll-top").click()` to `$("i.fa-chevron-up").click()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave the `<span id="scroll-top">` element `display: block`, which makes it take full width.

So if you change your click handler to `$("i.fa-chevron-up").click(...)` it will work

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hgu02x0b/7/)

---

Or you can change `<span id="scroll-top">` to `display: inline-block` and set `text-align: center` on the `footer`

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hgu02x0b/4/)

---

Or, since the `icon` has a fixed width, give `<span id="scroll-top">` the same width, `width: 34px` and center it using `margin: 0 auto`

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hgu02x0b/6/)

Comment: Chosen as the right answer because of 3rd solution. Very clean

Comment: Down voter, please comment so I can adjust any mistake made

Answer (score 3):

You have the span element displayed as block so it is covering the container width. you can take this out and text-align all children elements in .footer in the center

```js
$("#scroll-top").click(function() {
  alert('test');
});
```

```css
.footer {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.footer .fa-round {
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  height: 34px;
  width: 34px;
}

.footer #scroll-top {
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 99999999;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
    display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);

}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="footer">
  <span id="scroll-top">
  <i class="fa fa-round fa-chevron-up"></i>
 </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Any other way to center it without centering the whole footer div?

Comment: You can use the transform property, specifically translate

Comment: Also, you can simply set text-align left on your the parent and text-align center on the span with the arrow...hence the other children will not align in the middle

Answer (score 1):

You can be more specific on the element you are targeting, at the moment you are targeting the element with the id of `#scroll-top` but you can be more specific and target the icon element within that `#scroll-top i`

```js
$("#scroll-top i").click(function() {
  alert('test');
});
```

```css
.footer {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.footer .fa-round {
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  height: 34px;
  width: 34px;
}

.footer #scroll-top {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 99999999;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="footer">
  <span id="scroll-top">
  <i class="fa fa-round fa-chevron-up"></i>
 </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The span is set to `display: block`. This makes it take up the full row. You can change the jQuery to be more precise:

```
$("#scroll-top i").click(function() {
  alert('test');
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hgu02x0b/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Changed it to display:inline-block. http://jsfiddle.net/hgu02x0b/2/

```
.footer #scroll-top {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 99999999;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -17px;
}
```

Hope this helps